# How do I chain object instantiation with its methods?

Tags: python

For example this chunk of code:

```
new_log = ActivityLog(user=self.user,
                      activity=activity)
new_log.save()
```

Can I chain it to be like new_log = ActivityLog(...).save() ?

I believe I tried the above, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it a 1 liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides a convenience method on the model manager for just this purpose :-)

```
new_log = ActivityLog.objects.create(user=self.user, activity=activity)
```

The docs on [create are here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#create-kwargs). It is billed as:

> A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one step.

Answer (score 6):

Let `save()` return `self`, such as:

```
class ActivityLog (object): # EDIT: OR INHERIT FROM WHATEVER OTHER CLASS, I DONT CARE
    ...

    def save(self):
        ...
        return self
```

**NOTE:** This is a generic coding pattern called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Comment: I must be missing something... how does this work if ActivityLog doesn't inherit from models.Model?

Comment: what ` model.Model` ? There is no framework specific tag, just some generic python code. Please don't assume python == Django.

Comment: Well, you seem to have been right to assume that. However, this is a more generic coding pattern called "method chaining".